# R dplyr complete with multiple constant columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame("Name"=c("Bob", "Bob", "Emma"), "Age"=c(23,23,78), "Gender"=c("Male", "Male", "Female"), "Item"=c("house", "car", "house"), "Value"=c(5,1,3))
df
  Name Age Gender  Item Value
1  Bob  23   Male house     5
2  Bob  23   Male   car     1
3 Emma  78 Female house     3
```

I am trying to "fill" the missing rows with all the existing values of the "Item" column, knowing that the values of the "Age" and "Gender" columns are dependent on the "Name" one.

I try to get this result (see the 4th row) without joining two data frames together:

```
 Name Age Gender  Item     Value
1  Bob  23   Male house        5
2  Bob  23   Male   car        1
3 Emma  78 Female house        3
4 Emma  78 Female   car  unknown
```

I tried combinations of the `complete` function but it computes all possible combinations of the first 3 columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% complete(Name, Age, Gender, nesting(Item), fill=list(Value="unknown"))

  Name     Age Gender Item  Value  
 1 Bob      23 Female car   unknown
 2 Bob      23 Female house unknown
 3 Bob      23 Male   car   1      
 4 Bob      23 Male   house 5      
 5 Bob      78 Female car   unknown
 6 Bob      78 Female house unknown
 7 Bob      78 Male   car   unknown
 8 Bob      78 Male   house unknown
 9 Emma     23 Female car   unknown
10 Emma     23 Female house unknown
11 Emma     23 Male   car   unknown
12 Emma     23 Male   house unknown
13 Emma     78 Female car   unknown
14 Emma     78 Female house 3      
15 Emma     78 Male   car   unknown
16 Emma     78 Male   house unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was close:

```
df %>% complete(nesting(Name, Age, Gender), Item, fill=list(Value="unknown"))
 Name    Age Gender Item  Value  
1 Bob      23 Male   car   1      
2 Bob      23 Male   house 5      
3 Emma     78 Female car   unknown
4 Emma     78 Female house 3
```